# Upload multiple images as file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In my iOS app I want to upload an image file and some other parameters through API. image file contains multiple images.

Comment: Send the Service Request format

Comment: See my updated answer,how to pass other parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom image pickers like [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)

There is also some other library that can be used..
[WSAssetPickerController](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController)
[QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController)

These allow you to pick multiple images. let me know how things go

Answer (score 1):

By Using AFNetworking You can upload multiple image as below code, download [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

**Other Parameter :**

```
  NSDictionary *parametersAll = @{@"Value": @"Key"};

       NSArray *imageArray;
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseUrl: my_url ];

            NSMutableRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil
            parameters:parametersAll constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
                  for(UIImage *img in imageArray)
                  {
                        [formData appendPartWithFileData: my_imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"myImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                  }
            }];

            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

            [operation start];
```

Comment: How can i pass other parameters with this?